# android fragments in different tabs

Tags: android

I'm building an app that the interface is based on this http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/, and I need to have a fragment inside of each tab (that are fragments). The tabs are all inflated from the same xml, and in that xml I have a fragment tag.

The problem is that when the activity is created, as the id of each fragment in the tabs are equal, the contents that should go to the second tab, go in the first.

I'm using this code to replace the fragment in the tab

```
FragmentTransaction ft = x.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.details, fragment);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.commit();
```

I don't know if is possible to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

do you want all the tabs to have the exactly the same content?

Usually when putting fragments in tabs each tab would be showing differnt content, so a xml file per tab would not be uncommon. You can have a seperate xml layout for each tab that just declares your fragment with a different id each time. Without declaring a seperate (read unique) id for each fragment there is no efficent / simple operation i know to get a handle to a specific fragment (as the id is the unique handle).

You also may be able to use a [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) depending on your needs. You could then fade your current tab fragment out, then call [public void notifyDataSetChanged ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) and provide a new fragment. This is not really the standard way of doing it though and will not be preserved on the back stack.

<del>Optionally you could create each tab programatically in the `PagerAdapter` and set a `tag` for each fragment when calling [FragmentTransaction.add(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) and then use this tab-unique tag in future fragment transactions</del> Ignore this, it does not look like you can switch fragements with a tag, id only im afraid. Go with my first suggestion I would!

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer.
Yes I need the fragments to be equal.
Because they show diferent information, but with the same format.
I will give a try to your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with ths as well and the way I reference a `Fragment` from its `Activity` later on is by accessing the `Adapter` for the tabs.

Assuming you use an `Adapter`, you could do something like this

```
private mTabsAdapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // etc

    this.mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, this.mViewPager);

    // Tab1
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
    this.mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab, MyFragment1.class, null);

    // Tab2
    tab = actionBar.newTab();
    this.mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab, MyFragment2.class, null);
}

public MyFragment1 getTab1() {
    return (MyFragment1)this.mTabsAdapter.getItem(0);
}

public MyFragment2 getTab2() {
    return (MyFragment2)this.mTabsAdapter.getItem(1);
}
```

Then inside your fragment, you would have a method to access

```
public class MyFragment1 {
    // ...

    public void reloadData() {
        // reload data here
    }
}
```

Now you can access the `Fragment` such as

```
this.getTab1.reloadData();
```

This feels like a *sad* way to access a fragment, but you can't rely on a Tag in every scenario. Also, you must take care to only reference this where the reference to the `Fragment` exists.

There may be times that this will be *null*. For example if you nave a bunch of tabs, they may become garbage collected at some point. you should communicate between `Fragment`s via a callback. This example is for only a few scenarios.

The callback method is described at [Communicating with the Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) and I'd suggest this method if it fits your application. This will prevent the need for directly accessing tabs in most cases.